# Unwanted database during Azure deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I try to deploy my project into Azure, and while the publishing is successful, I always get the "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)" error.

I read/watched a few tutorials about publishing an asp.net project via Visual studio, and I noticed a difference between my project and those in the tutorials:

While others had only one database in the "Settings" section of their Publish window, I have two, and I don't know why. I figured that this may be the reason I get the error.

Here's my window:

[image: Publish settings for me]

And here's one from a tutorial:

[image: Publish settings in tutorial]

I don't really get this, because I should have only one database, like my server explorer shows:

[image: server explorer]

In my web.config file there's only one connection string defined, and that's for the DefaultConnection:

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-vocab_2-20130928092402;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-vocab_2-20130928092402.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I guess my DbContext-derived VocabModel class is also relevant:

```
public class VocabModel : DbContext
{

        public VocabModel() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
        {
            if (Membership.GetUser()!=null)
            {this.currentuser = UserProfiles.Find((int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey);}
        }

        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ForeignExpression> ForeignExpressions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PracticeResult> latestResults { get; set; }   

}
```

So what's wrong? Did I make a fundamental error with Entity Framework? (this is the first time I'm using it)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was the

```
if (Membership.GetUser()!=null)
        {this.currentuser = UserProfiles.Find((int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey);}
```

part in my model's constructor. I moved this code to the get method of the currentuser property (which is more logical anyway), and now it works as expected. Any explanation would still be appreciated. (Why did that part cause an additional database during publish?)